# WebAPI Controller error Handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I have a issue in implementing Error handling in Web-APi

```
[HttpGet]       
public UserAccount Get()
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        Content = new StringContent("My Error Message"), 
        ReasonPhrase = "Critical Exception"
    });
}
```

When I tried to call this method from my machine(site is hosted locally), it is working as expected. i.e I got the error message in response (plain text). But when I access the same url from another machine(LAN connected), response is IIS 500 internal error page. Here my problem is that, I am not getting the custom error message **"My Error Message"**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your web config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
```